# Profile wrongly suspended

Tags: discussion, account-suspension, appeal

I apologize for asking this question here, because I must ask it on Ask Ubuntu website where my account is suspended for a reason I see as unfair (because I deleted 10 of my former questions that were of bad quality, not even commented, not answered and very poorly visited), but this is not my question.

The moderator sent me a message in which he said he blocks my account for 3 days only, but I guess he did a mistake because he suspended me for 29 days. How can I fix this?

I have asked in the past through the contact form about other problems, but I never received an answer.

Comment: I cannot move the posting to meta.askubuntu.com: "Question owner is suspended".

Comment: @HendrikBrummermann Thank you for trying. Me too I tried to ask this on meta.askubuntu.com but I must have at least 5 reputation.

Comment: Did you try using "Contact us"?

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion yes, I did it already, but I'm not sure I will get an answer since I never received answers from that contact form in the past

Comment: @Begueradj: have you considered the possibility that the message from the moderator contained a typo instead? Suspensions are usually not for just 3 days, if you still have 29 days on the suspension then they probably meant to type *30* and missed out on the 0. Have you been suspended on Ask Ubuntu before?

Comment: @MartijnPieters You are right, it may be the case. But then, this makes the suspension more unfair regarding the long period of suspension and the good reasons for which I deleted my former bad questions

Comment: @Begueradj: reading the message now, it indeed could also have gone the other way, 30 typed into the days suspension textfield (perhaps autocompleted from the 3 the moderator meant to use).

Comment: @Begueradj: and if you are just 1 day into it, don't worry too much just yet. It has only been 1 day then, and it *is* a weekend just before the holidays.

Comment: Looks like you had account here on MSE and deleted it. Why? Is there more to the story than you shared? (e.g. past suspensions, which are looked at by moderators)

Comment: Did you delete the questions - or delete the content from the questions? The moderator message says "deface" not "delete".

Comment: @o̊ǝʇ̲ɐW⃗: what search did you use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I contacted the user, and I explained to him the actions taken. Especially the 30 day suspension, since he has been suspended before, and that there was no valid reason to delete the question, since most of them were only just asked recently.

He replied professionally, understanding the actions.